# What is the best way to catch canceled http request with Angular and RxJs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to catch canceled http request in order to retry it but I can't figure out how to achieve that.

I think maybe there's a method in RxJs that can tell me that my request is complete.

```
return this.http.get(blabla)
.map(
  (success) => success,
  (error) => error
);
```

The only thing I can do now is using the complete event in subscribe method:

```
.subscribe(
  (success) => success,
  (error) => error,
  () => {
    // Some code here
  }
);
```

Comment: Are you aware of the retry & retryWhen operators?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to use it with a canceled http request

Comment: Have a look at [This](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/retrying-http-requests-with-rxjs)

Comment: No, it never goes into any retry (retry or retryWhen)